# Porque no funciona mi javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function

En esta calculadora la función "calcularAlimento" a veces mi respuesta del código es correcta y a veces no lo es y no encuentro porque.

Cuando ingreso las cantidades y hago los cálculos me debería de dar diferentes respuestas dependiendo si el número "existmm" es mayor o menor que "totpv"

```
function calcularMm() {
            var hg = document.getElementById('hg').value;
            var hm = document.getElementById('hm').value;
            var hc = document.getElementById('hc').value;
            var fc = document.getElementById('fc').value;
            var b8 = document.getElementById('b8').value;
            var b16 = document.getElementById('b16').value;
            resultado = String((100) + (hg*170) + (hm*85) + (hc*43) + (fc*150) + (b8*250) + (b16*500));
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = resultado;
        }

function calcularAlimento() {
            var existmm = document.getElementById('existmm').value;
            var totpv = String(resultado / 3);
                if (existmm > totpv) {
                    document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML = Math.round(totpv);
                    document.getElementById('agua').innerHTML = Math.round(totpv);
                    document.getElementById('harina').innerHTML = Math.round(totpv);
                }
                else if (existmm < totpv) {
                    var gralim = String((resultado - existmm) / 2);
                    document.getElementById('agua').innerHTML = gralim;
                    document.getElementById('harina').innerHTML = gralim;
                    document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML = existmm;

                }
        }
```

Comment: Por qué un valor de una operación matemática la pasas a un valor string?

Comment: Ademas donde esta el codigo de la variable `resultado` para ver si no hay error ahi

Comment: lo puse en String porque sinceramente estoy empezando y todavía o entiendo muchas cosas. la variable resultado viene de otra funcion, ya la agregue a la pregunta

Comment: Con string es como si desearás ese valor como una cadena de texto, eso es lo que buscas como resultado?

Comment: No realmente, solo deseo obtener el resultado en numero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

intenta con `parseFloat(resultado/3)`
ya que lo estas convirtiendo en string  y este reduce su numero y con el float agarras todo los digitos
a parte de donde obtienes tu variable resultado

Comment: parseFloat parece ser la respuesta que buscaba

Comment: n.n que bueno que funcionara